# SSRS Oracle Query with Start and End Date Parameters

Tags: oracle, date, reporting-services, parameters

I've found lots of information on SSRS passing parameters but I haven't found one that worked for this query. I'm using SSRS to build a report but my query isn't working.

Could someone help me getting the start date and end date parameters to work? The w.startdtm field is a datetime field (e.g. 10/19/2003 12:00:00 PM)

I was getting the error message: 
[image]

This is my query right now:

```
select 
a. "Acct", a. "Dept",  a "Name", a. ID,  w. "Date", p. "Code", 
TRUNC(w.startdtm), 'dd-mon-yy')) "StartDate",

from a, w, p

where    TRUNC(w.startdtm), 'dd-mon-yy') between 
TRUNC(:StartDate), 'dd-mon-yy') and TRUNC(:EndDate),'dd-mon-yy')
```

Comment: first of all, you have something wrong with your brackets, shouldn't it be TRUNC(w.startdtm, 'dd-mon-yy') and TRUNC(:EndDate,'dd-mon-yy'); and second - change the date pattern to 'dd-mon-yyyy'.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my where clause to:TRUNC(:StartDate, 'dd-mon-yy') and TRUNC(:EndDate,'dd-mon-yy') but its still giving me the same message. I've also updated the field: TRUNC(w.startdtm, 'dd-mon-yy')

Comment: try 'dd-mon-yyyy' everywhere, not 'dd-mon-yy'